# Bridge determination in undirected graphs

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal

A bridge (critical edge) in an undirected graph is an edge whose removal increases the number of connected components.

I need to determine all critical edges in an undirected graph, in $O(V+E)$ time. From what I found out, I need to use a modified DF search, but all pseudo-code algorithms I found have `low[v]` and `d[v]` which I don't understand.

Can someone please explain to me the $O(V+E)$ bridge determination algorithm?

Comment: what is low[v], what is d[v]? how do you expect us to guess what was the purpose of this symbols? Finally did you look at wiki's page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_%28graph_theory%29#Bridge-finding_algorithm.

Comment: Yes, I looked. But I did not understand the algorithm on wikipedia. I mentioned low[v] and d[v] because I noticed these notations in a few bridge determination algorithms. I don't know what they mean. I was hoping someone could explain a bridge determination algorithm.

Comment: OK, you can show a sample algorithm that you couldn't understand it.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri 'code' dfs(G,v) { d[v] = time, time = time +1, low[v] = d[v], for each (v, u) in E, if(d[u] not defined) dfs(G,v), low[v] = min(low[v],low[u]), if(low[u] > d[v]), (v,u) is bridge, else, if u != parent of v, low[v] = min(low[v], d[u])

Comment: Edit your question and put your code there in good format. we will edit it as soon as you put the code, but in all if you cannot understand some code is better to ask it in codereview.stackexchange.com, but if you don't understand the algorithm, say which part is hard and may be we can help you.

Comment: If you show the algorithm by editing the question, as rightly suggested, choose preferably a pseudo-code version that is easy to read (and give the source, of course).